# Is this simple Single sign on soap token proposal safe?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap

We have a custom Single Sign On requirement that once a user has logged into to a portal they can go to another clients application and be signed in automatically with no messages.

I have looked at dotnetopenauth open id provider but i dont think its quite right for this as seems overly complex. There is a proposed solution from a client below but i would like to know if it is secure, less or more so that say open id etc. If open id sounds like a better fit for this please explain why and how to implement properly (there are not many good examples yes i have searched see a previous post that i have no help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23311063/how-to-implement-a-soap-webservice-for-api-to-api-open-auth-2-provider)

The proposed solution is:

**key**:

- Domain_Master (this is us)
- Domain_Client (clients applications, third parties, who need us to pass a logged in user to them so they can log them in their end)

SOAP messages over HTTPS.

Once a user is logged into Domain_Master they will click a link to Domain_Client with a secure token added to the URL. {token is encrypted and will contain a minimum of: timestamp, ClientID, and possibly a nonce}.

The Domain_Client will then upon receiving a secure token validate it with Domain_Master web service using SOAP. The SOAP response will tell Domain_Client who the user is and will log them in to the Domain_Client application accordingly. So basically its like a key to open a door.

The validity of the token (e.g. that it hasn't expired or has already been used etc.) will be done by Domain_Master in the SOAP API – Domain_Client will simply collect the token passed in the URL and query it directly with the Domain_Master SOAP API.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot confirm if this method is more or less secure, however my initial concern with the above method is that there is no validation of the token by domain_client. Without validation of this token, anything could be passed to domain_client and it would pass it straight to your web service at domain_master - this could lead to problems as it could provide an attack vector.

You could implement HMAC for validation of the token - http://www.piotrwalat.net/hmac-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api/

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your help.

The token is generated by domain_master and validated by domain master, if the token was not in a correct format and within the timestamp it would be ignored. Im not sure how a vector attack would be any less possible with hmac. i may be wrong. Anything further help be great Thanks.

Comment: HMAC authentication would prevent a specially crafted malicious token being passed to the domain_master web service via a direct call to domain_client.

Comment: thanks. i will read more into the hmac and vector token. With regards the rest of it, does it sound fairly feasible and sensible to build or is something like open id with dotnetopenauthid a better option. thanks again

Comment: did you think just by adding HMAC or similar this solution would be a good one for the requirement or can you suggest anything better. Thanks

Comment: It really depends on your business requirements if one is better over the other one, and each will have it's pros and cons. My answer was to help you with regards to the security of the solution you posted that had been proposed, and not on which one is better. 
I realise this doesn't help answer the question of which solution is better, however you will have to evaluate such things as time costs to your business of implementing either solution, based on the resources your company has. 
https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/wiki has some good information to help with this.

Comment: Thanks again for you comment. I have spent days well more than just days trying to evaluate and decide what to do to solve the requirement. I have downloaded the dotnetopenauth searched for hours on google read hundreds of articles etc but nothing really helping me to see why 1 things is better than another. I was hoping someone would have done b2b api auth/ open id or a wcf soap like proposed and say which was best and why tey cose it and even better if any code examples where given (but thats just a bonus). :-( thanks.